# Compare lines in multiple files and print each line containing the maximum value to a file

Tags: python

I wish to compare multiple files in a folder and output largest value of **DD** for each line compared to the corresponding lines of other files within the folder. Example: I have 10 files in a folder all of them containing some line with DD= some float values say -0.903999; i.e the format is **DD=-0.903999;** Each value is different of course. The result I expect is that after comparing ***line 1*** in ***file1*** with ***line 1*** in ***file2*** and ***line1*** in ***file3*** etc,  it should print the line with largest DD value in line 1 of the new file, same for line 2 and so forth.

Result so far: I am getting only 1 line of result per all files in the folders instead of lines containing max DD for line1, line2, line3, etc after comparing the files. I know I am on track but just this one bit. Thank you for the help

Here is what I have so far

```
    resultLines = []
    filemaxDD = -999999
    filemax = ""
    linemax = ""

    def myproces(root, file):
        f = open(os.path.join(root, file))
        mylines = f.readlines()
        maxline = ""
        maxDD = -999999
        global filemaxDD
        global filemax
        global linemax

        for line in mylines:
            if 'DD=' in line:
                stPos = line.index('DD=') + 4
                for i, s in enumerate(line):           
                    if (s == ';') & (i > stPos):    
                        break
                dd = float(line.__getslice__(stPos, i))
                if dd > maxDD:
                    maxDD = dd
                    maxline = line
        if (maxDD > filemaxDD):
            filemaxDD = maxDD
            linemax = maxline
            filemax = file[:-4]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirPath):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                processFile(root, file)
    resultLines.append(filemax + "     " + linemax)
    result_file = open('final.txt', 'w')
    result_file.writelines(resultLines)
    result_file.close()
```

Example files (with just two file and few lines).

```
file 1 contains this:

#searchE    google     yahoo     bing
  1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.1;f=0.5;i=3 
  1           0         2         h=2;DD=-0.6;f=1.2;i=1
  1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.2;f=0.5;i=3 
  1           0         2         h=2;DD=-0.6;f=1.2;i=1

file 2:

#searchE    google     yahoo     bing
  1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.2;f=0.5;i=3 
  1           0         2         h=2;DD=0.3;f=1.2;i=1
  1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.2;f=0.5;i=3 
  1           0         2         h=2;DD=-0.1;f=1.2;i=1
```

Result expected given above example lines:

```
              #searchE    google     yahoo     bing
file1.txt      1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.1;f=0.5;i=3
file2.txt      1           0         2         h=1;DD=0.3;f=0.5;i=3
```

Comment: Welcome to your first question on StackOverflow. Please show us an example file that shows your problem, along with the expected output, desired output, and the full traceback for any error message. Basically, show us just how you "seem to be stuck." Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Perhaps you should tweak your algorithm using a `key`-`value`-structure, where the key is e.g. `DD` and each time you parse a file, compare, whether the value has to be updated.

Comment: Please why was this downvoted?

Comment: I wonder why the down vote without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using readlines() method that throws the entire file into memory I would iterate over each file and read each of them line by line with readline(). It would look something like this:

**EDIT:**
Ok, let's assume that you are not working with enormous files and that you can easily throw all of their contents into memory. Here's the updated script:

```
import os
path = 'Files' # Path to directory
directory = os.listdir(path) # Get files in your directory
lines = []


# Forget about readline() method. Just dump all files into memory
fileData = []
for file in directory:
    with open(path + '\\' + file) as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        fileData.append(contents)


def formatPrint(file, data):
    '''Helper function to format print output'''
    print(file, "    %s    %s    %s    h=%s;DD=%s;f=%s;i=%s"%tuple(data))

def processString(line, filename):
    '''Extract useable information from a line in a file'''
    lineData = line.split() 
    firstThree = lineData[0:3]
    lastFour = lineData[3].split(';') # Not all values are separated by ' '

    # Just some formatting
    for i in range(len(firstThree)):
        firstThree[i] = int(firstThree[i])

    lastFour[0] = int(lastFour[0][2:])
    lastFour[1] = float(lastFour[1][3:])
    lastFour[2] = float(lastFour[2][2:])
    lastFour[3] = int(lastFour[3][2:])

    # Splice both lists together
    firstThree.extend(lastFour)
    completeLine = firstThree

    DD = completeLine[4]
    return filename, completeLine, DD

for i in range(len(fileData[0])):
    DDict = {}    # Dictionary DD : filename
    DataDict= {}  # Dictionary filename : data
    DDList = []   # List to keep track of DDs
    for k in range(len(fileData)):
        line = fileData[k][i]
        if line.strip() != '':
            f, data, DD = processString(line, directory[k])
            DDList.append(DD)
            DDict[DD] = f
            DataDict[f] = data

    maxDD = max(DDList)
    firstWinner = DDict[maxDD]
    formatPrint(firstWinner, DataDict[firstWinner])
```

Here are the files:

```
#File 1
1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.1;f=0.5;i=3 
1           0         2         h=2;DD=-0.6;f=1.2;i=1
1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.2;f=0.5;i=3 
1           0         2         h=2;DD=-0.6;f=1.2;i=1

#File 2
1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.2;f=0.5;i=3 
1           0         2         h=2;DD=0.3;f=1.2;i=1
1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.2;f=0.5;i=3 
1           0         2         h=2;DD=-0.1;f=1.2;i=1

#File 3
1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.4;f=0.1;i=3 
1           0         2         h=2;DD=0.2;f=1.2;i=1
1           0         2         h=1;DD=-0.1;f=0.3;i=2 
1           0         2         h=2;DD=-0.2;f=1.4;i=1
```

And here's the output:

```
File_1.txt     1    0    2    h=1;DD=-0.1;f=0.5;i=3
File_2.txt     1    0    2    h=2;DD=0.3;f=1.2;i=1
File_3.txt     1    0    2    h=1;DD=-0.1;f=0.3;i=2
File_2.txt     1    0    2    h=2;DD=-0.1;f=1.2;i=1
```

Did I get this right?

Comment: I understand this will be faster but do you mind elaborating on how it helps solve my current problem. Thank you much

Comment: This is not working as expected. I have elaborated more on what I was trying to do. Thank you

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Let me get back to you on this!

Comment: Alright, check out the edits. Let me know if it works now.